# Prisma. Javascript to Typescript

Tags: typescript, prisma

I am using Prisma with Javascript. It is working well. After upgrading to typescript, I have this error: 
`GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character ".".`

```
// index.ts

const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const { importSchema } = require('graphql-import')
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express')
const { Prisma } = require('prisma-binding')
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools')
import resolvers from './resolvers'


const { directiveResolvers } = require('./directives')



const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: './schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  directiveResolvers
})

const server = new ApolloServer({
  debug: true,
  schema,
  formatError: error => error,

  context: req => ({
    ...req,
    db: new Prisma({
      typeDefs: path.join(__dirname, './generated-schema.graphql'),
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:4466/nacho/prod'
    })
  })
})

const app = express()

const port = 9000
app.listen({ port }, () => console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`))
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es2016", "esnext.asynciterable"]
  },
  "exclude": ["test", "dist"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

then I run `tsc`, it works, then `node dist/index_server.js`, I have this error:

```
/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql/language/lexer.js:270
  throw (0, _syntaxError.syntaxError)(source, pos, unexpectedCharacterMessage(code));
  ^
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character ".".
    at syntaxError (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:15:10)
    at readToken (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql/language/lexer.js:270:38)
    at Object.lookahead (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql/language/lexer.js:54:43)
    at Object.advanceLexer [as advance] (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql/language/lexer.js:44:33)
    at Parser.expectToken (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1399:19)
    at Parser.many (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1514:10)
    at Parser.parseDocument (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:111:25)
    at Object.parse (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:36:17)
    at Object.buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/generate/buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions.js:19:33)
    at makeExecutableSchema (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/makeExecutableSchema.js:26:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alan/Documents/app/nacho/prismaTs/dist/index_server.js:29:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your `'./schema.graphql'` for a syntax error?

Whatever IDE you're using should have a plugin for reading graphql schemas, and should highlight syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks! But it works in JavaScript. The issue is the file schema.graphql doesn't exits in the folder dist after the compilation